# Detecting rotated/inverted images with PDFBox

Tags: pdfbox

I've got some PDFs which have images that are rotated and inverted. Sample of the image:

[image: inverted and rotated text]

The page object itself has no rotation instructions but it appears they may be using the cm operator in the content stream to perform the transformation for the rendered PDF:

```
...snip...
q
  0.05 0 0 -0.05 0 768 cm
  q
    0 0 11880 15360 re
    W*
    n
    /GS0 gs
    1 J
    [ ] 0 d
    2 w
    0 0 0 RG
    /GS0 gs
    1 1 1 rg
    /GS0 gs
    1 1 1 rg
    /GS0 gs
    1 J
    [ ] 0 d
    2 w
    0 0 0 RG
    q
      11865 0 0 15360 0 -3 cm
      /Image1 Do
    Q
...snip...
```

Am I on the right track here?

We're already using PDFStreamEngine to analyze images so I thought maybe using the current graphics state would have these available:

```
protected class DrawObjectCounter extends OperatorProcessor {
   @Override
   public void process(Operator operator, List<COSBase> operands) throws IOException {
       System.out.println(getGraphicsState().getCurrentTransformationMatrix());
       ...snip...
   }
...snip...
```

The output is always:

```
[1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0]
```

Do I need to keep track of the CM operators with another OperatorProcessor or am I just not looking in the right place?

Comment: Which `OperatorProcessor` instances have you registered in your `PDFStreamEngine`? Because you are on the right track to inspect the `CurrentTransformationMatrix`.

Comment: In this particular instance, I'm using a Do processor. I've also got a BI processor.

Comment: You could also use PrintImageLocations.java and look at "ctmNew".

Comment: Yeah, the matrix doesn't seem to have the values I'm looking for though. I got the AffineTransform out of it and it doesn't appear as I would expect. I'll see if I can create a sample project with a self contained test case. Maybe I have something else going on.

Comment: *"In this particular instance, I'm using a Do processor. I've also got a BI processor."* - you also need processors for **cm**, **q**, and **Q**. You can use `SetMatrix`, `Save`, and `Restore` from pdfbox.

Comment: OK, That was my backup plan. I thought the current matrix would have the value available. I assume I'll need to backup/restore the old matrix state on each q/Q to ensure I have the correct value when the image is drawn.

Comment: Oh, I think you're saying I can use the existing SetMatrix, Save, Restore processors and that will trigger the engine to save the correct matrix state? Sorry, I need coffee before I start responding to stackoverflow in the morning. Thanks, I'll give that a go!

Comment: ok, thanks for your help! It was Concatenation instead of SetMatrix but that did the trick. I'll add the answer in a bit.

Comment: Ah yes, `SetMatrix` most likely is for the text matrix while `Concatenate` is for the current transformation matrix. IMO those names could have been chosen better... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a problem in the construction of my PDFStreamEngine. I needed to register operators to perform the matrix modifications:

```
public PdfImageStreamEngine() {
    // pdfbox operators
    addOperator(new Save());
    addOperator(new Concatenate());
    addOperator(new Restore());
    // custom operators
    addOperator(new DrawObjectCounter());
    addOperator(new BeginInlineImageCounter());
    addOperator(new LineToCounter());
}
```

Once I registered the proper operator processors, the getCurrentTransformationMatrix had the correct value.